# What is the purpose of an MQ concentrator topology?

Tags: mq, amazon-mq

Amazon MQ (and various on-prem MQs) can be configured in a "concentrator" toplogy with a larger amount of brokers that forward their messages to a fewer number of central brokers. [image]

What is the benefit of such a setup? Is the idea the brokers on the bottom are distributed in different AZs or even regions?